# Is bypassing client-side protections a XSS vulnerability?

Tags: xss

While I am attending the private bug bounty program, I realized the web application has a hidden element and its value is an empty string in HTML code.

The app is using this element's value in some of the front-end works with Javascript. In addition to that, the application has got client-side XSS protection function written with Javascript. I open the developer console and delete this function and then change the value of the hidden element using `document.getElementById ("hidden_id").value='"><script>alert ()</script>'` and then immediately alert box popped up.

To sum up, I deleted the protection function from front-end and trigger XSS from the developer console. Is this XSS?

Note: There can't be server-side protection because the code running on the front-end. The malicious script doesn't go to the server-side. Just runs on the front-end.

Comment: I think this can be answered by looking at the definition of XSS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting XSS is defined by an injection that is viewed by others. In this case, you are writing code to yourself.

Comment: But the problem is control mechanism on the client side and I can modify the element's value. Local xss?

Comment: How do you convert this into an attack on someone else? From your description, you would have to get a target to go into developer mode, change the code, then add your new code. That's not XSS.

Comment: You can write your own malware and run it on your own machine, but that's not a vulnerability or an attack.

Comment: Ok, I understand this part. My new question is how can I create proof of concept for client-side protection based XSS attacks. Because we know that this protection is not enough but how can we convert this into an attack?

Comment: I'd suggest posting that as a new question.

Comment: You can inspect and edit the source of *any* page locally, and the changes will be visible to you. Now if you sent your edited webpage to someone and tricked them into opening it and executing malicious js, it could be considered [self-xss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Self-XSS), but it's still technically not a true xss vulnerability (after all, would you blame SE if you somehow convinced me to give you my SE credentials, or to run a script that does the same).